# EMCC not found - only works in emsdk not globally in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, global, emscripten, webassembly

I am a new Linux user and am looking to get the emscripten emcc command to work globally on Ubuntu.

This is my current configuration:

```
LLVM_ROOT = '/home/mpaccione/Projects/emsdk/upstream/bin'
BINARYEN_ROOT = '/home/mpaccione/Projects/emsdk/upstream'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT = '/home/mpaccione/Projects/emsdk/upstream/emscripten'
NODE_JS = '/home/mpaccione/Projects/emsdk/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin/node'
TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]
```

If I am in /var/www/html/collision-detection-wasm/hello-world
... command 'emcc' not found.

I followed the install instructions but they did not work how I would expect. I need this to work globally or it's not of use.

How do I go about doing that on Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: for anyone on windows, try to use wsl instead first

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `emcc` it needs to be in your `$PATH`.

To do this you can run `source /path/to/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh` in your terminal.

Or if you want to make it permanent you can add that same command to your startup scripts (e.g. `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc`).

This is documented at https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html.

Comment: Yes, so I did run the source command n my emsdk folder according to the docs but then it seemingly only adds it to that folder/parent directory. If I go up to var/www then it doesn't work. I will copy paste the emsdk_env.sh PATH's to my .bash_profile and see how it goes.

Comment: Yeah so I looked at the .bashrc file. There is no .bash_profile I can see. What am I supposed to type into the .bashrc file for this to work?

Answer (score 3):

Hijacking @sbc100's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127452/12351436) to further clarify things to answer OP's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122619/emcc-not-found-only-works-in-emsdk-not-globally-in-terminal#comment104488646_59127452) asked as a comment.

In order to use `emcc` one needs to set the PATH and other environment variables.

As it can be seen in the [documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#installation-instructions-using-the-emsdk-recommended), the command `source ./emsdk_env.sh` (or `source /path/to/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh` if you are not within the `emsdk` directory) does exactly that for the current terminal.

If you want this effect to be permanent, then do just as @sbc100's [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127452/12351436). Just add it to, for example, to your `bashrc` file by inserting `source /path/to/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh` to a new line at the end. This will make the script run each time a terminal opens. This may be annoying to same as it outputs what was added to PATH and which environment variables were set.

Alternatively, one may also add the entries to the `bashrc` manually that the script kindly tells us about. For me, it meant inserting the following lines:

```
## Emscripten ########
export PATH="/home/dudly01/repos/github/emsdk:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/dudly01/repos/github/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/dudly01/repos/github/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin:$PATH"
export EMSDK="/home/dudly01/repos/github/emsdk"
export EM_CONFIG="/home/dudly01/repos/github/emsdk/.emscripten"
export EMSDK_NODE="/home/dudly01/repos/github/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin/node"
```

I would think, however, that these lines need to be adjusted as the project evolves.

Comment: You can silence the output from emsdk_env.sh by putting this into you bash/zshrc `source /home/laurenz/checkouts/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh &> /dev/null`